# React Admin how to use Basic Authentification ? In my sample, Auth headers are well sent to the entrypoint, but not to all others endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, api-platform.com

i have an api that runs under /api
It requires Basic Http authentification (no needs of JWT thanks to this article https://jolicode.com/blog/why-you-dont-need-jwt).
So i configured my authProvider and my fetchHydra to build the Header.

This header is well sent to those 3 main endpoints:

- /api
- /api/docs.jsonld
- /Entrypoint

But then, it try to call all resources endpoint without using Basic Http so they all response with HTTP 401.

Here is my code:

```
// admin.js (app main resource)

import React from 'react';
import parseHydraDocumentation from '@api-platform/api-doc-parser/lib/hydra/parseHydraDocumentation';
import { HydraAdmin, hydraClient, fetchHydra as baseFetchHydra } from '@api-platform/admin';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import authProvider from './src/authProvider';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const entrypoint = document.getElementById('api-entrypoint').innerText;
// Fetch api route with Http Basic auth instead of JWT Bearer system
const fetchHeaders = {"Authorization": `Basic ${btoa(`${localStorage.getItem('username')}:${localStorage.getItem('token')}`)}`};
// original system with JWT
// const fetchHeaders = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`};
const fetchHydra = (url, options = {}) => baseFetchHydra(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders),
});
const dataProvider = api => {
    return hydraClient(api, fetchHydra);
}
const apiDocumentationParser = entrypoint =>
    parseHydraDocumentation(entrypoint, {
        headers: new Headers(fetchHeaders),
    }).then(
        ({ api }) => ({ api }),
        result => {
            const { api, status } = result;

            if (status === 401) {
                return Promise.resolve({
                    api,
                    status,
                    customRoutes: [
                        <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />} />,
                    ],
                });
            }

            return Promise.reject(result);
        }
    );

ReactDOM.render(
    <HydraAdmin
        apiDocumentationParser={apiDocumentationParser}
        authProvider={authProvider}
        entrypoint={entrypoint}
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
    />, document.getElementById('api-platform-admin'));
```

```
// admin/src/authProvider.js

import { AUTH_LOGIN, AUTH_LOGOUT, AUTH_ERROR, AUTH_CHECK } from 'react-admin';

// Change this to be your own authentication token URI.
const authenticationTokenUri = `${document.getElementById('api-entrypoint').innerText}/login`;

export default (type, params) => {
    switch (type) {
        case AUTH_LOGIN:
            const { username, password } = params;
            const request = new Request(authenticationTokenUri, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password }),
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
            });

            return fetch(request)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) throw new Error(response.statusText);

                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(({ token }) => {
                    localStorage.setItem('username', username);
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token); // The token is stored in the browser's local storage
                    window.location.replace('/');
                });

        case AUTH_LOGOUT:
            localStorage.removeItem('username');
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            break;

        case AUTH_ERROR:
            if (401 === params.status || 403 === params.status) {
                localStorage.removeItem('username');
                localStorage.removeItem('token');

                return Promise.reject();
            }
            break;

        case AUTH_CHECK:
            return localStorage.getItem('token') ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();

        default:
            return Promise.resolve();
    }
}
```

My application is using PHP Symfony Api-Platform (2.4.5) and Api-Platform Admin (0.6.3 which embed the react admin ^2.7.0)
I pushed the repo on github: https://github.com/Rebolon/LibraryManagementSystem

Comment: My guess is that `fetchHeaders` is initialized only once and when local storage is empty. Make it a function and call it for every fetch.

Comment: @FlorianF. it doesn't seem to be the proble, because i make it works for JWT based on official docs: https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/authentication-support/ And after login is ok, the 1st 3 calls to entrypoints are OK (so header are well setup) by not next calls.
Even with a function call, it's executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem is not related of my code. Oh yeah, it's not my fault.
In fact it's related to version 0.6.3 of package @api-platform/admin which breaks the authentication system.
The solution is to rollback to version 0.6.2 of the package.

Thanks to this thread: https://github.com/api-platform/admin/issues/185

Comment: Unfortunately, this ended up being the fix for me too, I don't even know exactly why its broken it just won't work at all.